# Use defined attributes and passing n number of attributes to wrapper using only one decorator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, wrapper, python-decorators

I am learning to use decorators and I can't figure out how to pass already defined attributes to the wrapper without making a function specific decorator.

Let's say I have a decorator :

```py
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Before the function")
        func()
        print("After the function")

    return wrapper
```

With this I am only able to use it with functions with only defined attributes or without any attribute like :

```py
@decorator
def foo1(attribute1=10, attribute2=20):
    print(attribute1, attribute2)
    return

foo1()
```

But it makes me unable to run :

```py
foo1(1, 2)
```

With this problem, I also can't use this decorator on different functions that don't have the same amount of attributes to set.

So, it there a way to fix this problem without the use of `*args` and `**kwargs` or at least without having to call a function that would look like this : `foo((arg1, arg2, argn))`? Because it would make me unable to define any attribute. This is my only restrain.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that "attributes" are things on an object, e.g. ``list.sort``. What you have here are arguments (the things passed to a function, e.g. ``1, 2`` in ``foo1(1, 2)``) and parameters (the things received by a function, e.g. ``a, b`` in ``def foo(a, b): ...``).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper has to accept arguments (because it replaces the original function bound to the decorated name), and those arguments have to be passed to `func`.

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Before the function")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("After the function")

    return wrapper
```